# parse simple XML for sequence of tags using sed (or some other standard tool)

Tags: xml, bash, parsing, sed

I have some simple XML in a form like the following:

```
<event>
    zappo
</event>
<event>
    wappo
</event>
```

I want a simple Bash function to return the content of one of the "event" elements. The function could be used in a manner such as the following, where the integer (2) is used to specify which element to return:

```
command:
    myFunction myFile.txt 2
output:
    wappo
```

I am somewhat familiar with the program XMLStarlet, but I need to do this using more standard tools found on Linux. Could you point me in the right direction on this?

Comment: Sed can work if the file follows a strict format, but it is probably the wrong tool for the job. Awk is probably a better choice, and easier to write it in...

Comment: you most likely [do not want](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348) to parse XML using regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

xmlparser would be safe way to go.

If for some reason, you have to do it with text processing tool, awk could work for this, but you have to be sure that the file format is strictly follow the format in your question.

```
awk -v n="$idx" '/<event>/{++i;p=1;next}/<\/event>/{p=0}p&&i==n{print}' file
```

you just need to pass in the `$idx` (could be shell variable), and it will output the right block for you. for example:

```
kent$  cat f
<event>
 one
</event>
<event>
   two
</event>
<event>
    three
    sss
</event>
<event>
    four
</event>


kent$  awk -v n="3" '/<event>/{++i;p=1;next}/<\/event>/{p=0}p&&i==n{print}' f
    three
    sss 
kent$  awk -v n="2" '/<event>/{++i;p=1;next}/<\/event>/{p=0}p&&i==n{print}' f
   two
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this with `GNU awk`, but bear in mind, `awk` and `sed` are not meant for `xml` parsing. There are specialized  tools out there which will be ideal for a job like this.

With `awk`, you can do:

```
awk 'NR==2*n' n="2" RS='</?event>' ORS='' xml
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat xml
<event>
 one
</event>
<event>
   two
</event>
<event>
    three
    sss
</event>
<event>
    four
</event>
$ awk 'NR==2*n' n="2" RS='</?event>' ORS='' xml

   two
$ awk 'NR==2*n' n="3" RS='</?event>' ORS='' xml

    three
    sss
$ awk 'NR==2*n' n="4" RS='</?event>' ORS='' xml

    four
```

Answer (score 0):

The:

```
perl -0777 -MXML::Simple -nlE '$x=XMLin($_);say $x->{event}->[0]' < file.xml
```

will prints:

```
zappo
```

and

```
perl -0777 -MXML::Simple -nlE '$x=XMLin($_);say $x->{event}->[1]' < file.xml
```

prints

```
 wappo
```

But you need valid xml. Your xml is not valid XML, only valid xml-fragment. So, if your file is really like the above - you can run the command as next:

```
(echo '<root>';cat file.xml;echo '</root>') | perl -0777 -MXML::Simple -nlE '$x=XMLin($_);say $x->{event}->[0]'
```

But you need to have `perl` and installed the `XML::Simple` module.